# Java - Floating point with limited decimal places but without coma

Tags: java, decimal

I'm developing a graphics computing application for my Computer Science course. I'm doing many calculations over vectors, but sometimes i'm getting some severe truncations since it's float arithmetics.

The problem is I tried some ways of limiting the decimal places of float numbers to, for example, 2 places. Here are some things I tried:

1 - Divide and multiply by 100. This do not work all the times. Actually this never works for me.

2 - Use a DecimalFormat. This way of formating works well if i have numbers under 1000. When I have numbers such 1003.3124 it formats to 1,003.31 . Since this formating returns a String, the parse function for Floats do not works because of the coma. I tried to set the DecimalFormatSymbols() setGroupingSeparator to different chars, includind the no space and the no lenght char ( '\u0200B', '\u0000', ... ), but I get '?' instead of the desired char.

3 - Set the Locale to US. Since my Windows is running in Brazillian Portuguese ( here the dot and the coma have different papers: yours 1,300.42 is ours 1.300,42! ) I think this is stupid, but it's not the question here. This solved nothing too.

4 - Take the String, remove the comas and return the Float number. This is what i'm doing now and it's working correctly. However, since it's a graphics application, i'm doing normalizations all the times with the numbers. So a String solution is always too heavy.

So do you know of another way of solving this issue? I need the most optmized one. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: You want to limit the decimal places just for display, or for internal  storage/computation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you just use `float` to calculate and if you want to display the numbers with exactly 2 digits after the dot/coma you use `String.format`.

Trying to do it in the RAM to optimize calculations is probably not a good idea, as floats are already a primitive type that is extremely optimized by Java and the hardware.

Comment: Probably it's what I gonna do. No need to limit floats in memory. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you are dealing with display issues or internal storage/computation. If the later, read about [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

IF your problem is just of display, then use the appropiate DecimalFormat. I quite don't  understand what you mean by "Since this formating returns a String, the parse function for Floats do not works", why do you want to parse it?

Comment: I want to Parse to store the new formated Float. I'll look into the BigDecimal. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this problem could be to cast your float as an integer after multiplying by 100, then casting it as a float after doing that. Example:

```
float x = 20;
float y = (float)Math.PI;
float total = (float)(int)((x+y)*100)/100;
```

I'm not sure how well this works memory wise, or speed wise, but it's certainly one way to do it.

Comment: This do not works for Floats. I've tried it wit double and it's good enough, but for some reason Float's don't get changed.